# Windows 10 roaming profile task bar icons

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, taskbar, icons, microsoft-office-2016

I have an issue when pinning Office 2016 icons to the taskbar then moving between 32- and 64-bit machines using a roaming profile.  Essentially, if logging into a different architecture than when the shortcut was pinned, the icon displayed is a "blank sheet of paper" icon (see https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GRMiMlF.png)

As the shortcut icons sit under "Program Files/Microsoft/Office", this causes an issue due to the difference between "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)".

I have tried to change the icon shortcuts to point to the two system variables %programfiles% and/or %programfiles(X86)%, but these are the same as the physical locations (ie they don't work).

- I could get the user to re-pin everytime they switch PC... (not
  likely!)
- I could create a manual icon repository on the fileserver,
  and alter the shortcuts to point there (re-pinning would break this)
- I could install the 64-bit version of Office, but no-one makes a compelling argument to switch away from Microsoft's default install option (plus any
  potential add-in/COM issues...).
- I could update the OSes to 64-bit
  (for some reason before I took over, they had 32-bit Win7 on 64-bit
  machines, and automatically updated to 32-bit Windows 10), but that
  will take a good day or so and a 2 and half hour drive to get there 
  (the affected PCs are in a small company where we have remote
  desktop/VPN access to for support, but no auto-provisioning of machines)

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: You should upload your image to imgur instead.  Website your choose to upload to doesn't work for me.

Comment: Solution: Install 32-bit Office to Program Files on a 64-bit installation.  "I could install the 64-bit version of Office, but no-one makes a compelling argument to switch " - You have made your own compelling argument to switch.  You wouldn't have this shortcut problem if you were using a 64-bit installation of Office on a 64-bit OS and a 32-bit installation on a 32-bit installation.  Of course as you conclude just using 64-bit operating systems in 2017 would also be a solution

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this is an inherited setup and I haven't done much to "break" it yet!  I suspect you are right with the 64-bit office re-install, just seems a little overkill for some icons...

Comment: It is overkill.  Some of your pain is you are using roaming profiles.  Additionally I suspect you could solve this by not allowing icons to be pinned to the taskbar.

Comment: How about using `mklink` to create symbolic links? For example, system with 32bit installs, make a symbolic link in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\winword.exe` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\winword.exe`.

Comment: Update on the comment, it's probably a lot easier just to mklink `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office`.